# Javascript Modify First Word

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Surely there's a better way of doing this? It's not very elegant. I'm simply wanting to make the first word bolder.

```
let title_array = title.split(" ");
title_array[0] = "<strong>"+title_array[0]+"</strong>";
title = title_array.join(" ");
```

Comment: I don't think, this is wrong way. That's good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is good, below is another approach using Regex

```
var title = "Hello to new StackOverflow";
title = title.replace(/^(\w+)/, '<strong>$1</strong>');

console.log(title);
```

```js
var title = "Hello to new StackOverflow";
title = title.replace(/^(\w+)/, '<strong>$1</strong>');

console.log(title);
```

Since you are using React, you may have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render the html.

So another approach would be something like this in React.

```
<div>
{
   title.split(" ").map((word, index) => {
     return index === 0 ? <strong>{word}</strong> : ` ${word}`;
  });
}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm loving the use of map, and not having to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML :)

Comment: Kiranvj how would I address the unique "key" prop issue?

Comment: @AlanMontefiore `key` issue can handled in different ways. One example would be      `return index === 0 ? <strong key={index}>{word}</strong> : <React.Fragment key={index}>{\` ${word}\`}</React.Fragment>` ;

Answer (score 4):

I think your current approach is fine. You do have the option of using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#description) also with a regular expression:

```js
const title = "This is a title";
const boldTitle = title.replace(/^[^\s]+/, "<strong>$&</strong>");
console.log(boldTitle);
document.body.innerHTML = boldTitle;
```

Here, the regular expression matches non-whitespace characters (`[^\s]+`) from the start of the string (`^`) until it reaches a whitespace character (`\s`). This match is then used in the replacement (referenced using `$&`)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a CSS class. [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) can help with defining the words, and you can use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to return the result.

```js
function embolden(str) {
  const [ first, ...rest ] = str.split(' ');
  return `<span class="bold">${first}</span> ${rest.join(' ')}`;
}

const title = 'Javascript Modify First Word';
document.body.innerHTML = embolden(title);
```

```css
.bold { font-weight: 700; }
```

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity purposes when coding, please use arrow function combined with RegEx to make it shorter.

```js
const boldFirstWord = strTitle => strTitle.replace(/(^|\.\s)([a-z]+)/gi, "$1<strong>$2</strong>");
console.log(boldFirstWord("We simply love JavaScript!!!"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you have proposed is ok, but I don't think you should use `<strong>`, maybe this would be a better approach depending on the case:

```js
let title_array = title.split(" ");

title_array[0] = `<span style="font-weight: 700">${title_array[0]}</span>`;
title = `<p>${title_array.join(" ")}</p>`;
```

Comment: You're making a recommendation with no supporting argument. Why not use `strong`?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, `strong` is for semantic purposes. Since the example does not provide any context, I think just styling the word is ok.